# ssh works on IP get "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host" on FQDN

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have a new raspberry pi box running at my home. I decided that I will use it to access it by ssh from the web. I setup the NAT in the Router and everything else, from my Mac Book within the internal Network. Working at home with the IP of the raspberry pi to access it by ssh. Now when I try to connect to the box from outside with exactly the same host, from the outside, I get

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

The crazy thing is, I have an iOS ssh Client, and that one is working on the internal and external Network with the FQDN.

I checked within the last two days tons of tutorials and wikis, changed a lot in the sshd, nothing helped. My Client do not show up within hosts.deny and I set the hosts.allow to **SSHD: ALL** already. I am a little bit clueless.

Checking the **auth.log** with sshd on debug Level I do not even get a message that my client is trying to connect. While IP still works and the iOS ssh Access works all the time like a charm.

---

Because it seems I wrote that above a little bit confusing, her some additional information:

I have my RaspberrPi and I enabled ssh on it.

Tested it and did some work on it by doing a ssh pi@192.168.0.22 from ClientA

Than I setup the Router to do a NAT, so that I also could access my RaspberryPi by ssh from the Internet. All that work was done from ClientA.

Now while at my office I did from ClientB an ssh to my Raspberry Pi by ssh pi@mypi.at that worked :)

Than I took ClientA with me on a trip and while in another place I did  ssh pi@mypi.at which returned me ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
So, a little bit confused, I used ClientB and I was connected without any Problems. I tried even a ClientC and that one worked too.

So back at home, I tried to ssh pi@192.168.0.22 and I was connected without any Problems. But when I tried to use the FQDN it keeps telling me ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host.

I used ClientB and ClientC also on the internal Network and both are working with FQDN and with IP, so I am confused, why ClientA can only access be IP (of course ClientA is the box I use the most)

Comment: It working within the network is normal.  This indicates the service is running.  It not working outside the network indicates the port isn't configured to be forwarded to that particular device.

Comment: The Port is running fine from the outside, because I can use other ssh clients to contact the raspberry pi from the outside. So that seems not to be an Network issue as I can contact it from the outside even by Phone and Tablet.

Comment: I am confused then.  If other ssh clients can connect ( which isn't clear by reading the question ) what exactly is the question?

Comment: okay, maybe I wrote it a little bit confusing.
I will append something

Comment: maybe the description above helps a little more :)

Comment: Its normal for you to be unable to use a FQDN within an intranet situation.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that, nevertheless it works with the other two clients. The question is, why I can not connect ClientA on the Internet with the FQDN nor the public IP?

Comment: Because the FQDN is only valid outside of the intranet.  Your other two clients are not within the intranet of the host.

Comment: Look,  I have three clients. And two of them can access the Pi from the Internet, the third one can't. All of them, can access the Pi when they are within the intranet, using the IP.

Comment: Are you asking the reason this specific client is unable to do it, in which you provided NO INFORMATION ABOUT, or are you asking a broad question about the reasons you wouldn't be able to.  As I said in a typical NAS setup its normal for you to be unable to access the host within the same intranet using the public address.

Comment: Sorry, for that. Yes, I want to know the reason why ClientA can not connect. It is a OS X 10.9.3 box. It can connect within the intranet but on the internet it will get the error as described.

Comment: The Pi is also on the latest Patch-Level. ClientA does also not show up on the hosts.deny file. Also, within the auth.log no error appears while ClientA connects.

Comment: What if you ping the hostname? What if you ping the FQDN?

Comment: Both Pings work, as I mentioned the connectivity works. The Problem is not a DNS issue or connectivity on the network side. There is a Problem within the sshd.

Comment: you could try ssh -vvv and you could try looking for clues in wireshark at the difference between the connection that works and the one that fails